# Fewest digits to get floating point that doesn't round trip through string?

Tags: floating-point

Given a string `s` representing a real number in decimal notation, `to_float` returns the nearest IEEE double-precision float to that number.

Given an IEEE double `f`, [`to_string`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_positional.html) returns the shortest string `fs` such that `to_float(fs) == f`. E.g., using the Dragon4 algorithm

---

My question is: What is the shortest string, which is a valid non-NaN, finite number, such that `to_string(to_float(s)) != s`?

I've tried brute-forcing this, but only managed to check strings up to 7 digits + a decimal point

```py
def check_numbers_up_to_n_digits(n):
    STR = np.format_float_positional
    FLOAT = float
    rngs = [tuple(range(1, i)) for i in range(n + 1)]
    for x in map(''.join, itertools.product('0123456789', repeat=n)):
        x = x.rstrip('0')
        if x == '': continue
        if x[0] == '0':
            s = '0.' + x[1:]
            if STR(FLOAT(s)) != s:
                print(repr(s))
            continue
        for d in rngs[len(x)]:
            s = x[:d] + '.' + x[d:]
            if s[-1] != '.' and STR(FLOAT(s)) != s:
                print(repr(s))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a loophole in your question: there are many different strings representing any given numeric value, and `to_string` can only produce one of those, so `to_string(to_float(s)) != s` is trivially easy to achieve: just use `s = "1.00"`, or `s = "+1"`, or `s = "123_456"`, or `s = "1e-006"`, etc. For the specific `to_string` you're using in your search code, even just `s = "0"` is enough, since that converts back to `"0."`.

The more interesting question (and the question I think you're really asking) is: rather than simply being unequal on a character-by-character basis, what's the shortest `s` for which `to_string(to_float(s))` and `s` represent different *values*? Below, I'll answer that question.

First, the answer: there are many such shortest strings, but they all have 16 significant digits, and hence the string must have length at least 16. `s = "9007199254740993"` is an example. If you insist on a decimal point being present in `s`, then we'll need at least 17 characters in the string.

Now to the justification: suppose that `s` is a decimal numeric string that represents a real number with at most 15 significant digits. Let's make it positive, for simplicity (zeros are boring, and the negative case doesn't introduce anything new or exciting). So in other words, `s` is a string representation of a real number of the form `m * 10**e` for some integers `m` and `e`, with `0 < m < 10**15`.

Now let's convert `s` to the nearest IEEE 754 binary64 float (rounding ties to even as usual in the case of a tie), and then convert that float back to the nearest precision-15 decimal value, again rounding ties to even where necessary. (This isn't using the "shortest-string" conversion yet; we'll get to that below.)

Then it's a well-known property of floating-point base conversions that in this case, *provided* that `s` doesn't lie outside the range of normal binary64 values, we recover the original decimal value.

In other words, the composition of round-ties-to-even correctly-rounded conversions of floating-point numbers:

```
{precision-15 decimal} -> {precision-53 binary} -> {precision-15 decimal}
```

round trips, assuming either unbounded exponents, or that we avoid the extremes of the exponent range.

For proofs, see ["In-and-out conversions", by David Matula](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/362851.362887). For an informal, hand-wavy intuitive justification, a key point is that if you compare 15-digit decimal floating-point with 53-bit binary floating-point, then the binary format is everywhere finer on the positive real-number line: if you pick any irrational number `x`, then the spacing between the two nearest binary floats to `x` is strictly smaller than the spacing between the two nearest decimal floats to `x`. The inequality that guarantees this is that `10**15 < 2**(53-1)`. (FWIW, I also wrote up my own proof [here](https://github.com/mdickinson/float-proofs/blob/master/misc/base_conversion_notes.pdf).)

For some evidence, you can try the following in Python:

```py
>>> from random import randrange as rr
>>> from decimal import Decimal as D
>>> while True:
...     s = f"{rr(10**15)}e{rr(-300, 290)}"
...     t = format(float(s), '.15g')
...     assert D(s) == D(t)
```

Here we're repeatedly constructing a random 15-significant-digit string with random exponent, converting to `float`, converting back to a string with 15 significant digits, and then converting both numeric strings to `Decimal` (that conversion is exact) to compare their values. The `while True` loop should run indefinitely. Note that this assumes a version of Python that uses IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point, and for which `float` and float formatting are correctly rounded.

Now for the shortest string conversions: it follows from the fact above that the conversion from 15-digit decimal strings to binary64 must be *injective*: different 15-digit decimal strings must give different binary64 values. (Again, avoiding overflow and underflow; I'll stop mentioning this caveat from now on.) So *if* there's a 15-digit decimal string that converts to a given float, there's only one such.

So in the case that we started with a 15-digit decimal string `s`, if `fs` is the closest binary64 float to it, we already know that `s` converts to `fs`, so `to_string(fs)` must give something equivalent in value to `s`. So you won't find interesting examples where `to_string(to_float(s)) != s` unless `s` has more than 15 significant digits.

But as soon as you start looking for examples with 16 significant digits, there are many. The most obvious is `s = "9007199254740993"` (`9007199254740993` being `2**53 + 1`).

Comment: Thanks! I clearly struggled to phrase the question right, so appreciate you reading between the lines. And answering of course!

Comment: I guess the only piece to add is that you can't get underflow/overflow with 15 digits. IUC, overflow is at `s > 2**1023` and underflow is at `abs(s) < 2**-1022`, which take hundreds of digits to spell out in decimal

Comment: Well, the statement does cover things like `"1.23451234512345e-300"` (which round-trips as expected): i.e., strings that still have only 15 significant digits but a large exponent that shifts things near to the underflow / overflow region. But you get problems if you try to extend this much further. At the extreme underflow end, for example, `"4e-324"` round-trips to `"5e-324"`.

Comment: "with 0 < m < 10**15" - I'm assuming you meant "0 < m < 10" and "0 <= e <= 15" or something in that area?

Comment: @faho: I really did mean `0 < m < 10**15`. `m` here is playing the role of the significand in a floating-point representation. For example `3.14159265358979` is an example of a number that fits this description. It's equal to `m * 10**e`, with `m = 314159265358979` and `e = -14`.

Comment: In that case, you might want to give the range for e - "-15 < e < 0"?

Comment: @faho There's no range for `e`: `e` is unbounded in this context. So for example `12345123451234500000000000000000` and `0.00000000000000000123451234512345` are also values that fit this format. In both cases, `m = 123451234512345`; in the first case, `e = 17` and in the second case `e = -32`.